# Is there a way to reduce the contrast of the screen without dimming it?

Tags: applications, settings, 5.1-lollipop, screen

So I was trying for the umpteenth time the other day to watch video content in bright sunlight, and it occurred to me that if I had some kind of app that reduces the contrast by raising the level of black to dark gray rather than lowering the level of white, the picture would be a lot more viewable. I searched for such an app, but all the ones I found that claim to control contrast have a dimming effect. I don't want to dim the screen. Does anyone know how I can keep the screen bright and still achieve the desired result? I'm using an LG VS810PP (Transpyre) running Android 5.1.1 Lollipop.

Comment: Could this be a hardware issue? Could my phone be so old that the backlight isn't bright enough anymore? The phone was used when I purchased it, and I've used it a lot in the nearly 2 years since then. I don't remember having outdoor viewing issues when I first got it.

Comment: One way of achieving the desired result might be to subtract the colors from maximum, apply an ordinary contrast algorithm, subtract the result from maximum again, and apply the result to the pixel, then repeat the process for the next pixel, etc., etc. May require a large amount of computing power.